# CSS Multiple Animations on single element, no javascript

Tags: html, css, animation, css-animations

I am trying to create an image slideshow using only CSS and no Javascript.

I have an ALMOST working example here: http://codepen.io/k/pen/Dkhei .
The problem is that the animation for the 'Previous' functionality won't pause when I stop hovering over its element.

I am defining two animations on a single element, whose class name is 'imageContainer'. I am curious to know whether my syntax is wrong or if what I am trying to do is not possible.

HTML:

```
<div class='carouselContainer'>
<div class='directionSelector previous'>Previous</div>
<div class='directionSelector next'>Next</div>
<div class='imagesContainer'>
  <img class='visible' src='http://ibmsmartercommerce.sourceforge.net/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/Roses_Bunch_Of_Flowers.jpeg'/>
  <img class='hidden' src='http://houseoflowers.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/Splendid-flowers-wallpaper-wallpapers-1920x1200-mrwallpaper-com.jpg'/>
  <img class='hidden test' src='http://wallzpoint.com/wp-content/gallery/flower-4/flower-flowers-31723005-1600-1200.jpg'/>
  <img class='hidden' src='http://images2.layoutsparks.com/1/179204/no-idea-t5-flowers.jpg'/>
  <img class='hidden' src='http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-Ca_H0XQYQI4/UQFMSauQxTI/AAAAAAAABik/WHzskd_HqqU/s1600/flowers.jpg'/>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.carouselContainer{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  width: 450px;
  height: 300px; 
  position: relative;
  background-color: grey;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.directionSelector{
  width: 60px;
  height: 1.5em;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  top: 150px !important;
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: rgba(1,1,1,.7);
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.previous{
  top: 0;
  left: 5px;
}
.next{
  top: 0;
  right: 5px;
}
img{
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  float: left;
}
.imagesContainer{
  width: 100%;
  background-color: yellow;
  -webkit-animation-name: showImagesPrev,showImagesNext;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 5s,5s;
  -webkit-animation-play-state: paused,paused;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards,forwards;

  -moz-animation-name: showImagesPrev,showImagesNext;
  -moz-animation-duration: 5s,5s;
  -moz-animation-play-state: paused,paused;
  -moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards,backwards;

  animation-name: showImagesPrev,showImagesNext;
  animation-duration: 5s,5s;
  animation-play-state: paused,paused;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards,backwards;

}
.previous:hover ~ div.imagesContainer{
  -webkit-animation-name: showImagesPrev;
  -webkit-animation-play-state: running; 

  -moz-animation-name: showImagesPrev;
  -moz-animation-play-state: running; 

  animation-name: showImagesPrev;
  animation-play-state: running; 
}
.next:hover ~ div.imagesContainer{
  -webkit-animation-name: showImagesNext;
  -webkit-animation-play-state: running;

  -moz-animation-name: showImagesNext;
  -moz-animation-play-state: running;

  animation-name: showImagesNext;
  animation-play-state: running;
}
@-webkit-keyframes showImagesPrev{
  from{
    margin-top: 0px;
  }
  to{
    margin-top: -1200px;
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes showImagesPrev{
  from{
    margin-top: 0px;
  }
  to{
    margin-top: -1200px;
  }
}
@keyframes showImagesPrev{
  from{
    margin-top: 0px;
  }
  to{
    margin-top: -1200px;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes showImagesNext{
  from{
    margin-top: -1200px;
  }
  to{
    margin-top: 0px;
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes showImagesNext{
  from{
    margin-top: -1200px;
  }
  to{
    margin-top: 0px;
  }
}
@keyframes showImagesNext{
  from{
    margin-top: -1200px;
  }
  to{
    margin-top: 0px;
  }
}
```

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: This doesn't appear to be the cause of the problem, but there may be a typo with the `animation-fill-mode`. One of them is `forwards,forwards` and the other two are `forwards,backwards`.

Comment: I think this may only be doable if it's possible to reverse the direction of a single animation at any point. I experimented with using a single animation and toggling `animation-direction` between `normal` and `reverse` (for next and previous), but that didn't seem to work.

Comment: @Matt, had the same thought and tried to get it to work too... no luck either. But I think it's the right way.

Comment: The problem arises when at the exit of the hover there is a change in the animation, in anything that is not the play state. I have also tried changing direction, as @MattCoughlin. It has the same problem. But, you can make the previous work changing the animation when not hovered to match(in both approaches). Only that then the next will stop working :-)

Comment: can use :active instead of hover? then you can animated by image like a slideshow.

Comment: @Matt: Oh I missed that. I just double checked how it works on chrome and it seems to work better with both fill properties set to forwards.

Comment: @Linus (AND MATT): I also tried changing the direction property when hovering on either PREV or NEXT when I first wrote this up.  Had no luck. Darn :/ Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As per W3C `animation-name` property [Link](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-animations/#animation-name-property)

> If multiple animations are attempting to modify the same property, then the animation closest to the end of the list of names wins.

In your example `showImagesPrev` is referred first and `showImagesNext` was the last one, so it worked correctly as per W3C. If you interchange these two reference, `Previous` will work fine, while `Next` button reproduce the issue. A working [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/bWxmq/1/)

Comment: the same problem haunted me 2 years ago. Glad to find the answer now!