# How to make this rectangle object fade in and then execute another animation?

Tags: css, css-animations

I am trying to make this rectangle **fade in and then play the second animation**? However at the moment it does not fade in and after few seconds just plays the second animation.

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/s3vtqrcy/)

HTML CODE:

```
<div class="rectangle firstAnimation thirdAnimation"></div>
```

CSS CODE:

```
@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
@keyframes fadeIn {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
.fadeIn {
    -webkit-animation-name: fadeIn;
    animation-name: fadeIn;
}
.rectangle {
    position:fixed;
    width: 300px;
    height: 36px;
    opacity:0.8;
    margin-top:215px;
    background: #212e84;
    z-index:1;
}
.firstAnimation {
    animation-name: fadeIn;
    -webkit-animation-name: fadeIn;
    -moz-animation-name: fadeIn;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 1s;
    animation-delay: 1s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 1s;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 3s;
    -moz-animation-duration: 3s;
    animation-duration: 3s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    -moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
@-webkit-keyframes movingbox {
    0% {
        left:0px;
    }
    100% {
        left:-157px;
    }
}
.thirdAnimation {
    animation-name: movingbox;
    -webkit-animation-name: movingbox;
    -moz-animation-name: movingbox;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 4s;
    animation-delay: 4s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 4s;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 3s;
    animation-duration: 3s;
    -moz-animation-duration: 3s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    -moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```

Comment: It's because two animations on the same object, try to have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15821245/css-multiple-animations-on-single-element-no-javascript

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot set two different animations under two different selectors in CSS as the latest (or more specific) declaration would overwrite the previous one.

The way to apply more than animation to a single element would be to set comma separated values to the the `animation` setting like below:

```
.thirdAnimation {
    animation-name: movingbox, fadeIn; /* specify multiple animations in CSV format */
    animation-delay: 4s, 0s; /* first value is delay for 1st animation, next is for 2nd */
    animation-duration: 3s; /* when only one value is provided, the same applies for both animations */
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```

Setting `animation-delay` as `0s` for the fadeIn animation would make it start immediately and the `animation-duration` being `3s` means, it would complete before the moving box animation starts (after a 4s delay). You can play around with `animation-delay` and `animation-duration` as required.

```css
@keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@keyframes movingbox {
  0% {
    left: 0px;
  }
  100% {
    left: -157px;
  }
}
.rectangle {
  position: fixed;
  width: 300px;
  height: 36px;
  opacity: 0.8;
  margin-top: 15px; /* reduced to make it visible in snippet window */
  background: #212e84;
  z-index: 1;
}
.thirdAnimation {
  animation-name: movingbox, fadeIn;
  animation-delay: 4s, 0s;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
<div class="rectangle thirdAnimation"></div>
```

<sup>**Note:** In snippet, I have used prefix-free library to avoid all the browser prefixing.</sup>

Comment: It's probably a good idea to change the class "thirdAnimation" to "allAnimations" :)

Comment: @l19: Yea, true but its a small change and if I edit again it would look like I am unnecessarily bumping the question up for rep and so leaving it as-is :)

Answer (score 0):

Simillar kind of issue here: [CSS Multiple Animations on single element, no javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15821245/css-multiple-animations-on-single-element-no-javascript)

Solution: http://jsfiddle.net/kybernaut/vuzzmoxj/1/

change class only to one, for example "Animation" and than css:

```
.Animation {
    animation-name: fadeIn,movingbox;
    -webkit-animation-name: fadeIn,movingbox;
    -moz-animation-name: fadeInmovingbox;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 3s,4s;
    animation-delay: 3s,4s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 3s,4s;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 3s,3s;
    animation-duration: 3s,3s;
    -moz-animation-duration: 3s,3s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    -moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```